# ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.1

Tags: android

i have imported import org.jsoup.Jsoup in my project, i got error while adding this dependency **i am currently using android studio 3.5.2**

```
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.1'
```

please suggest me a correct dependencies to resolve from this

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

> maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

to your repositories section in the build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```